# Press Enter key using shell script

Tags: macos, shell

I am using vb script file to simulate pressing of keys on Windows. My file code looks like this:

```
strKeyToPress = WScript.Arguments.Item (0)

KeyPress strKeyToPress

Function KeyPress(strKeyToPress)

lclTime = Now
Do
    If Datediff("s",lclTime,Now)>3 Then
        Exit Do
    End IF
Loop

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.sendkeys (strKeyToPress)

End Function
```

I then called it in my java code like this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript \"C:/Test/file.vbs" + "\" \"" + "{ENTER}" + "\"");
```

This works on Windows but now I am looking its equivalent on mac osx. I tried using robot class instead to press key but it didn't work.

I did some research and found out that I can do this by shell script but I not sure how can I simulate keystrokes using shell scripting.

Any Ideas?

Thanks